# Observable.create vs Observable.fromPublisher

Tags: rx-java

I have two function use create() and fromPublisher separately:

```
       Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            emitter.onNext("MindOrks")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }.map { s->
            System.out.println("map: "+s)
            s+s
        } .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .subscribe {
                System.out.println("DelayExample"+ it)
            }
```

The output is :

```
   map: MindOrks

   DelayExampleMindOrksMindOrks
```

How ever if I use code:

```
          Observable.fromPublisher<String>{publisher->
            publisher.onNext("MindOrks")
            publisher.onComplete()
        }.map { s->{
            System.out.println("map")
            s+s
        } }.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .subscribe {
                System.out.println("DelayExample"+ it)
            }
```

It returns:

```
  DelayExampleFunction0<java.lang.String>
```

I don't understand why return  "DelayExampleFunction0<java.lang.String>", and map function is never called , can anyone explain it ?

Comment: Note that `Observable.fromPublisher` is not meant to be for a typical user: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#fromPublisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher- . Using it like you did may result in hangs, crashes and generally undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional pair of braces "{}" in `map` function:

```
map { s->
     {
      System.out.println("map")
      s+s
     }
}
```

So in this case you're returning function, which returns string.
Change this to

```
.map { s ->
        System.out.println("map")
        s+s
}
```